# Creating partition with __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__ value

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is it possible in Hive to manually create partition with `\__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` value?

Neither of this works for me:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (partition=);
ALTER TABLE table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (partition='');
ALTER TABLE table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (partition='\__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');
```

P.S. Dynamic partitioning doesn't suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround if you specify the location explicitly:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (partition='[none]') LOCATION ('/location/path/partition=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');
```

This approach has the downside that the column "partition" in your table will have the string value '[none]' instead of actual null, but it is better than no partition at all.